# Private Artifactory Package not showing up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, artifactory

in the past hour I used Visual Studio to package a NuGet `.nupkg` file, and then used the following commands to push my .nupkg file to a private artifactory repo:

```
$ nuget sources Add -Name Artifactory -Source https://myurl/artifactory/api/nuget/ult-testware-nuget -username aaaaaa -password bbbbbb
$ nuget setapikey aaaaaa:bbbbbb -Source Artifactory
$ nuget push ClassLibrary2.1.0.0.nupkg -Source Artifactory
```

I can verify that it was uploaded and is visible online:
[image]

My private artifactory url is added to vscode as a NuGet source:
[image]

But when I try to browse for NuGet packages using that source, I get no results. Even with prerelease checked, and after refreshing/restarting VS, [image]

Do I need to re-authenticate Visual Studio with my private JFrog Artifactory repo somehow? I'm hoping to see and download the NuGet package I just pushed up.

I also tried adding to my NuGet.Config file another NuGet source:

```
    <add key="ArtifactoryNuGetV3" value="https://myurl/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/ult-testware-nuget" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
```

But that does not work.

One of the artifactory source urls I added links to my repo, and when I selected it to browse, I get a popup asking for username/password. After entering I get an error saying 404 (so I think the auth was a success, but its searching for my package in the wrong place)

```
[artifcator2] The V2 feed at 'https://myurl/artifactory/ult-testware-nuget/ClassLibrary2.1.0.0.nupkg/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='netcoreapp3.1'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 '.
```

If I remove everything from the url so it is just `https://myurl/artifactory/ult-testware-nuget/ClassLibrary2.1.0.0.nupkg/` and look it up in my browser, it either shows
`404: "{\"error\":\"Expected a folder but found a file, at: ult-testware-nuget:ClassLibrary2.1.0.0.nupkg\"}"` or If I remove the last slash it begins to download

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639412/nuget-package-in-artifactory-does-not-show-up-in-available-packages-in-visual-st) can help you?

Comment: I've looked through the post and tired the comments with no luck

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same issue, were you able to fix it somehow?